# multiple query vs batch performance with Mybatis in Spring

Tags: mysql, performance, spring-mybatis

I have one question.

**multiple query vs batch with mybatis in Spring**

example)

case 1. **allowmutiquery=true and  one call**

```
call "mutiquery" ;

<mapper id= 'mutiquery' > 
     <foreach>
             update ... set  .... 
     </foreach>
<mapper>
```

case 2. **loop multiple call and batch execute**

```
for( ; ; ){
  call "batch" ;
} 

<mapper id="batch">
     update ... set  .... 
</mapper>
```

what is the way better?

Comment: Please note that the [tag:batch-file] does not mean processing many files. You can hover on a tag to see its meaning. Thanks!

Comment: thank u , i was remove the batch-file tag.

Comment: Find out what SQL statement(s) are generated; from that, database gurus can advise.  (There are lots of db gurus; many fewer Spring gurus.)